# Looking for a particular value inside a list in python and getting error as TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to do some hand on in pyspark and from a particular sample file, for package "Rcpp", I want to know how many rows belong to it. I did below in pyspark to get the required result

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("<filepath>/2015-12-12.csv")
rdd=lines.map(lambda x: x.split(',')[6])
totalbypackage=rdd.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
data=totalbypackage.take(10) 
#this was just to view the first 10 records
print(type(data))
print(data)
```

For the above code, I get below results

[('"package"', 1), ('"HistData"', 159), ('"RJSONIO"', 1358), ('"UsingR"', 151), ('"gridExtra"', 1758), ('"lme4"', 1560), ('"testthat"', 1178), ('"mvtnorm"', 999), ('"maps"', 1586), ('"sp"', 1020)]

This is just first 10 records and its a list. As the type of data is list.
When I try to do below, I get error as list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
print(data["Rcpp"])
```

After reading to other question related to same error, I understand that we cannot use a string value. So how can I access value for "Rcpp" from the list?
Do I need to convert list into a dictionary?

Comment: If you know where "Rcpp" is, you can get index position.

Comment: I have provided the answer below. From an improvements point of view, I would suggest to reduce the usage of take() or collect() to the bare minimum as these convert the rdd/dataframe to a list which is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the list to a dictionary might be an option, but I would not recommend doing it. It pretty much destroys the motive of using pyspark/spark in first place.

Note that you are trying to perform an action statement when you use `take(n)`. `take(n)` will convert n records to a list which is not very efficient when the number of distinct "package" increases (what if you have 1 million kind of packages?). Using `filter()` before `take()` will be a much better, efficient and good-looking approach.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

lines = sc.textFile("<filepath>/2015-12-12.csv")
rdd = lines.map(lambda x: x.split(',')[6])
totalbypackage = rdd.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

# Filter only the count record in which we are interested
rcpp_count_record = totalbypackage.filter(lambda x: x[0] == "Rcpp")

# Now as we only have 1 row, we can use take(1) or collect() to get only the count part
print(rcpp_count_record.take(1)[0][1])
print(rcpp_count_record.collect()[0][1])
```

Both the print statements will display the count of "Rcpp" packages on console.

Comment: Hi @nishant, I used take to understand the data. Thats it. Just to look at some records like we do head -10 in unix. I will not be really using it in programming. Sorry, if I wasn't that clear on what i was trying to do. your answer and explanation definitely helps. After reading more through this,I used filter. What I did is that I first used a filter on RDD and then map function to get the count.  I got the required results. However, as it has many Rcpp like "Rcpp11", "RcppProgress", I am now trying to figure out how to just filter a specific one, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `data` consists of key-value pairs, the natural data structure to use is a dictionary. Then you can access any value by its key, for example:

```py
data = [('"package"', 1), ('"HistData"', 159), ('"RJSONIO"', 1358), 
        ('"UsingR"', 151), ('"gridExtra"', 1758), ('"lme4"', 1560), 
        ('"testthat"', 1178), ('"mvtnorm"', 999), ('"maps"', 1586), 
        ('"sp"', 1020)]
data_dict = dict(data)

print(data_dict['"sp"'])
```

```
1020
```

You may also want to change the code so that each key only has a single pair of quotemarks.

Comment: Thanks @Arne for your quick response, Looks like this will work for Python but not RDD. I am not able to convert my RDD into a dict and when I do data_dict = dict(data), i get error as pyspark: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable. RDD is not iterable. Looking for some help on SPARK RDD here.

Comment: I have upvoted for your answer because it helps with respect to python:-)

Comment: Is the use of an rdd a constraint? If yes, you could use the above example to manipulate data (using for instance a udf) and obtain the desired result

Comment: This approach pretty much destroys the motive of using pyspark in first place. Converting our data to a list/dictionary is not a good way as a list/dictionary is not processed in a  distributed fashion.

Comment: @NishantChaudhary, thank you for looking into this and providing your valuable feedback. Just to let you know, I am completely new to pyspark and trying some hands.